# How can I make my CSS toggle state changing smoother e.g. with a transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a toggle in CSS:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle', function () {
        $( this ).toggleClass( 'enabled' );
    } )
} );
```

```css
.checkbox-toggle-wrapper {
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle:not(.enabled)::before {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
}

.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle:not(.enabled) {
    border-color: #999;
    background-color: #999;
}

.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle {
    height: 16px;
    width: 32px;
    border: 2px solid #00695c;
    background-color: #00695c;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border-radius: 10em;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-toggle-wrapper">
  <span class="checkbox-toggle enabled"></span>
</div>
```

I'm looking now for a way to make everything a bit more smoother. I've tried out setting transition: `transition: all .3s` but this seems not to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle:not(.enabled)::before {
  right: 100%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

To make sure you can apply transition to right and transform

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('enabled');
  })
});
```

```css
.checkbox-toggle-wrapper {
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle:not(.enabled)::before {
  right: 100%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle:not(.enabled) {
  border-color: #999;
  background-color: #999;
}

.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle {
  height: 16px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #00695c;
  background-color: #00695c;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border-radius: 10em;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition:0.3s all;
}

.checkbox-toggle-wrapper .checkbox-toggle::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition:0.3s all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-toggle-wrapper">
  <span class="checkbox-toggle enabled"></span>
</div>
```